# C++ UWP Storage Access

Tags: c++, uwp, uwp-xaml

After rescap capability configuration and privacy setting File system allow still we cannot access File system and other drives to read file and configure model path for open pose in c++. I have tried many possibilities i cant access assets folder *.png file also.

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming by the carets after the types that this is C++.net, not C++. Additionally, please post your code, not an image of your code, in order to make debugging easier for the rest of us. We can't copy-paste an image.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability you won't be able to access an arbitrary path on the file system with ordinary APIs, you have to use the `StorageFile`/`StorageFolder` APIs instead. From the screenshot I see you are trying to read the image using OpenCV, so instead of using a path, you will need to read the image using a `StorageFile` and use a different `imread` overload which accepts a byte array or stream. Alternatively, you could copy the file from the given path to `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` which is accessible using any API, including `imread`